# Hadoop NullWritable for RCFIle Format Files

Tags: hadoop, hive, writable

I couldn't quite understand the concept of NullWritable in Hadoop. What is it used for and why is the outputKeyClass for an `RCFile` format a `NullWritable.class` and outputValueClass a `BytesRefArrayWritable.class`?

Answer (score 2):

This is because there is no key for a RCFiles.  When you read from a plain text file such as a CSV, the key is usually a byte offset into the file.  Since RCFiles have a columnar storage format, there's not really a key that can be used to identify a row as rows are fragmented across different column sets.  `NullWritable` essentially means `ignore this value`.

Answer (score 1):

"The Map and Reduce functions of MapReduce are both defined **with respect to data structured in (key, value) pairs**" ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce)).

It means that your data must be structured in (key, value) pairs. But sometimes there is no need to use a key, and you cannot set it to `Null` because a key must implement `WritableComparable`. That's why Hadoop created a `NullWritable` class.